# Codeigniter URL problem! Hitting refresh causes functions to be executed!

Tags: php, codeigniter, refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access a variable in a PHP class that is set by another function? Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885287/how-to-access-a-variable-in-a-php-class-that-is-set-by-another-function-codeigni)

I have a controller called submit:

Basically it does two things of concern:

1. **validate_form()** - It validates a form -> then submits to
   database.
2. **success()** - It loads a page giving feedback on whether the
   previous operation was successfull.

My controller works fine however there is a slight problem in when it loads my success page.
If you hit **Refresh** the "success" page it would for some reason cause my validate_form() function to run again causing the same data to be duplicated in the database.

**What I want is that when the user goes to success page they can hit refresh as many times they like and it wont call any functions etc.**

My url on the success view is

> http://localhost/site/validate_form

I am guessing this is the problem because it is still in the validate_form() function.

My validate form function loads the success view by calling another function within it?
Here is my code:

```
//Record ID = returned value
                        $record_id = $this->submit_model->create_record($completedstaffrows, $completedeventrows);

                        //if no value returned call failed function

                        if ($record_id == FALSE)
                        {
                            $this->failed();
                        }

                        //Submittal to database was successful
                        //Now call function to load success view
                        else
                        {

                            $this->success();
                        }
```

My function for loading success view:

```
    public function success()
        {
            $page['page'] = 'success';

            $this->load->view('template', $page );

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. After the form is submitted, make a 301 redirect to the same page, maybe with a session variable to know whether the data was valid or not, and this would prevent any duplicate data issue on refresh.

Comment: Ok I tried a redirect however I now have a problem that my variable that I was passing the original way is not getting passed to the view and is causing an error (undefined). How can I pass a variable using redirect?

Comment: You can use [CI sessions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) to store/retrieve values between requests. Take a look at the flashdata section, it would do the work you need.