# How to access a variable in a PHP class that is set by another function? Codeigniter

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, variables, attributes

I have this code here in PHP using Codeigniter framework, I can't seem to get my head around class variables in this code seems completely different to C++.

I was wondering how I can get a local variable in one class (function) method to another class method.

But not passing them as variables as I have to use a redirect function instead which cannot take variables.

The variable I want to have accessible is **$record_id** , i tried making it public etc does not like it.

class Submit extends CI_Controller
{

```
function send_data()
{
        $record_id = $this->submit_model->create_record($completedstaffrows, $completedeventrows);

                        if ($record_id == FALSE)
                        {
                            echo "Failed to add to database";
                        }

                        //Submittal to database was successful
                        else
                        {

                            redirect('submit/success');
                        }
                        return;
                    }
```

This is the function that I want to have access the **$record_id**

```
public function success()
{

$page['page'] = 'success';
$page['record'] = $record_id;
$this->load->view('template', $page );


}
```

**Remember** - I cannot pass this as a variable to the other function as I need to use a redirect so that my URL will not screw up. Thanks

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use codeigniter's tiny feature called Flashdata which allows you to have temorarily store data between requests.

so your code would be

```
function send data{
$this->session->set_flashdata('recordid', $recordid);
}

function success{
 $recordid =  $this->session->flashdata('recordid');
}
```

got it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Submit extends CI_Controller {

    private $record_id=false;

    public function __construct(){
         if(isset($_SESSION['record_id'])){
              $this->record_id = $_SESSION['record_id'];
         }
    }

    public function send_data(){
        $this->record_id = $this->submit_model->create_record($completedstaffrows, $completedeventrows);
        $_SESSION['record_id'] = $this->record_id;
        if ($this->record_id == FALSE){
            echo "Failed to add to database";
        }
        else{
            redirect('submit/success');
        }
        return;
    }
    public function success(){

         $page['page'] = 'success';
         $page['record'] = $this->record_id;
         $this->load->view('template', $page );
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not gonna get `$this->record_id == false` at success() function()?, because I suppose when a redirect is made, we reload the controller again, but it will go to success() method with `$this->record_id` placed with a false value due to the new instance for the class.